# Best way to handle a django request that will take a long time to process

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have a single page app I'm building in Python and Django that requires a substantial processing time to execute some functions (20+ minutes).

I'd like to user to be able to 'kick off' the process and then receive a notification when it is done (and possibly some progress updates as it executes).

One option is to make a view and then make an ajax POST to that view... but that means they can't leave the page or navigate the rest of the site while the request executes.

What is the best solution for something like this?

Comment: take a look at this: https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks

Comment: You should probably use something like celery or django-channels. A task that takes that long should not be run in a synchronous wsgi request.

Comment: if it is not completly overload, set up an rabbitmq server and let him do the work. I would send an email after completion together with the link of the result.